# MYSQL error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (FEDORA LARAVEL)

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel, docker

I have an aplication that works with angularjs and its backend is on Laravel. I'm working on Fedora 37.
The back is in a docker container, and I have a local database with mysql.
When I try to query anithing to the database, it brings the next error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
> `usuarios` where `email` = admin@test and `usuarios`.`deleted_at` is
> null limit 1)

The .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wymaq
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Frontend is located in localhost:9001, and its linked in config.app.js to back (localhost:8080) like this:

```
.constant('API_CONFIG', {
    'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', etc...
```

My database.php file is configured like this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'modes'       => [
                'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
        ],
```

In windows, there is no problem. I have the database in another container and it works. I tried it here in fedora but its the same error.

I get my mysql socket and its: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

When i type `php -i | grep pdo` in the back container i get this:

> pdo_mysql.default_socket => no value => no value

Comment: I tried it with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 or I tried with the docker container IP when i have the database in one of these, but same error.

Comment: You don't have to use an IP (unless the database container is in the same container as PHP), if it is not, you have to use the database container name as an address... please, do share the docker compose you have

Comment: At this moment I am using my SQL locally, so I have installed my SQL server in my machine. I was using another container for database but no more.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I do local dev w/ docker, and a SQL database (running on the host), the host name for the database that works for me is: `host.docker.internal`